# How can i use ASIHTTP Request in My Project?

Tags: ios4, asihttprequest

Hi I want to Implement ASIHTTP Request in my Project so how can i implement it and how it is good compare to NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are extensive descriptions on ASIHTTPRequest [setup](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) and [usage](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) on project site. Read it carefully and if you still have any specific questions after that ask them.

Note that ASIHTTPRequest does not include any parsing frameworks so to parse server response you'll need another libs

Answer (score 0):

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file